# MySQL/ Как обьеденить 2 строки запроса в одну?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно возвращать только одну строку тогда и только тогда, когда они полностью идентичны за исключением временной метки (в одной строке NULL, а в другой стоит время)

Мой sql запрос:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.type,
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.user_id,
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.department_id,
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.balls,
    TIME(modx_sm_tt_checklist.saved_at),
    DATE(modx_sm_tt_checklist.date),
    modx_user_attributes.mobilephone,
    modx_user_attributes.state,
    modx_user_attributes.fullname,
    modx_sm_departments.shortname,
    modx_sm_profiles.position
FROM
    modx_sm_tt_checklist
LEFT JOIN
    modx_user_attributes
ON
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.user_id = modx_user_attributes.internalKey
LEFT JOIN
    modx_sm_departments
ON
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.department_id = modx_sm_departments.department_id
LEFT JOIN
    modx_sm_profiles
ON
    modx_sm_tt_checklist.user_id = modx_sm_profiles.user_id
WHERE
    `name` != 'ЧЕК ЛИСТ ОТКРЫТИЯ' AND `name` != 'ЧЕК ЛИСТ ЗАКРЫТИЯ' AND modx_sm_tt_checklist.department_id = '12345678-4444-55-5555-123456789012' AND `type` BETWEEN 0 AND 1 AND fullname LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY
    TIME(modx_sm_tt_checklist.saved_at)
```

[image: Текущий результат]

Comment: Группировка по всем полям, кроме "Время завершения контроля", по которому брать, скажем, MAX().

Comment: @Akina, тоесть мне в GROUP BY все поля прописать нужно кроме временной метки, а к временной метке применить агрегатную функцию?

Comment: Я только говорю, как перейти от двух записей к одной на именно показанном примере. Как по мне, так весь приведённый запрос - это одно большое недоразумение, существующее лишь по причине отключенного ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, работает! Приму ваш ответ если ответите или отвечу сам позже :)

Comment: @Akina на сколько я могу судить, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - это серверная настройка mysql, мне кажется не лучшим решением сейчас ее устанавливать, так как это обычно не требуется. Лучше группировать вручную в частных случаях, к тому же проект уже до меня много лет разрабатывался, наверняка возникнут ошибки.

Comment: *на сколько я могу судить, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - это серверная настройка mysql, мне кажется не лучшим решением сейчас ее устанавливать, так как это обычно не требуется.* o_O [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)